# How do you add an object to a jQuery collection at a specified index?

Tags: javascript, jquery, single-page-application

I am creating a JavaScript class that represents a data-bound table, using jQuery to handle DOM manipulation. The class has a `$table.$body.$rows` property where I am keeping a collection of the table's jQuery-wrapped rows to avoid performing a `$table.$body.children('tr')` call whenever a row is added or removed. When a row enters or leaves edit mode, I need to be able to add and remove objects from that `$table.$body.$rows` property, which I accomplish with jQuery's `.add()` and `.not()` methods.

These methods are inadequate, however, when the row being edited is not at the very end of the table, since the `.add()` method adds the new item to the end of the internal collection maintained in the jQuery instance. In order to make sure the `$table.$body.$rows` collection is correctly ordered, I need to be able to *insert* the new item at a specified index within the jQuery collection. Does such a method already exist, or am I going to have to write it myself?

I could just let the `HTMLTableSectionElement.rows` property keep track of the rows for me and simply wrap a particular row in an jQuery object when necessary, but this seems inefficient. This raises a secondary question: how expensive is a call like .children('tr') anyway, and would I be better off simply reassigning `$table.$body.$rows` each time a row is added or removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Technically, [jQuery *do* add `splice()` to `jQuery.fn`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/bf48c21d225c31f0f9b5441d95f73615ca3dcfdb/src/core.js#L113), but it isn't documented. [They almost removed it](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2365) from the public interface recently, but decided against it;

   > We want to avoid the appearance that using these methods [jQuery.fn.{push,sort,splice}] is encouraged, but we don't want to remove them either.

   ... make of that what you will.
2. You *could* use `Array.prototype.splice.call`, e.g.:

   ```
   Array.prototype.splice.call($table.$body.$rows, 3, 0, newItem);
   ```

   ... and I can't see how that'd be wrong.
3. Although in all honesty, I think you're trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist.

   > I could just let the HTMLTableSectionElement.rows property keep track of the rows for me and simply wrap a particular row in an jQuery object when necessary

   ... I'd do this. Calling `.children('tr')`, and updating `$table.$body.$rows` when rows are modified is not going to kill your application.

Comment: So which approach is more performant: updating `$table.$body.$rows` using `.children('tr')` or wrapping rows from `HTMLTableSectionElement.rows` with `$()` as needed?

Comment: The difference will be negligible. In both cases, you're building a jQuery object from a DOM node you've *already* resolved, so in neither case will you need an expensive (in relative terms) DOM query. jQuery has [always optimized the case of being passed a DOM element](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/9d820fbde6d89bc7a06e2704be61cf6c0b4d6e3c/src/core/init.js#L97-L104). Having said that... be aware of micro-optimizations here. Does 0.00000001ms really matter? You could always (and should) profile it if so to be sure... http://jsperf.com

Comment: That makes sense. I figured the jQuery constructor logic is probably pretty trivial when you are working with HTMLElement objects directly, but I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 0):

You could the [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) function on the native array object.

`arr.splice(index, 0, item);` will insert `item` into `arr` at the specified `index`.

Comment: The jQuery class doesn't have a splice method, though. Or does it? It's not in their documentation at any rate.